# Using str_detect to select items between curly brackets

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a column of items like this

```
{apple}
{orange}>s>
{pine--apple}
{kiwi}
{strawberry}>s>
```

I would like to filter it so that I only get items that are NOT just a word between brackets (but have other stuff before or after the bracket), so in this example I would like to select these two:

```
{orange}>s>
{strawberry}>s>
```

I have tried the following code using `dplyr` and `stringr`, but even though on https://regexr.com/ the regular expression works as expected, in `R` it does not (it just selected rows in which the `var` column is empty. What am I doing wrong?

```
d_filtered <- d %>% 
  filter(!str_detect(var, "\\{(.*?)\\}"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pattern is saying "match anything where there are brackets, with or without stuff between them". Then you negate it with `!`, so filtering out anything that has a `{` followed by a `}` anywhere in the string.

Sounds like what you want to keep strings if there is something before or after the brackets, so let's match that. A `.` matches any (single) thing, so a pattern for "something before open bracket" is `".\\{"`. Similarly a pattern for "something after closing bracket" is `"\\}."`. We can connect them with `|` for "or". In your `filter`, use

```
filter(str_detect(var, ".\\{|\\}."))
```

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem by testing if all character within the vector is within `[a-zA-Z]`, `{` or `}`:

```
cl=c("{apple}",
"{orange}>s>",
"{pine--apple}",
"{kiwi}",
"{strawberry}>s>")
find=function(x){
  x=unlist(strsplit(x,""))
  poss=c(letters,LETTERS,"{","}")
  all(x%in%poss)
}
cl=cl[!sapply(cl,find)]
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you're excluding non-letters. OP says they want to keep strings like `{orange}>s>` that have `>` in them, and says nothing about "letters and brackets only".

Comment: I'm actually excluding everything that is letter and brackets only. `cl[!sapply(cl,find)]` is there for that, although maybe I should've done it inside `find()`.

Comment: Ah, I see. But it doesn't return OP's desired result because it returns `"{pine--apple}"`, which has nothing outside the brackets, just because it has non-letters inside the brackets. And OP would want to keep a string that *didn't* have the `>`, something like `{orange}s` they would still want to keep.

Comment: I agree. This `{orange}s` would be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

One can also use `grep` of base R:

```
> d = c("<s{apple}", "{orange}>s>", "{pine--apple}", "{kiwi}", "{strawberry}>s>")  
# I have added "<s" before {apple} in above vector

> d[grep(".\\{|}.", d)]
[1] "<s{apple}"       "{orange}>s>"     "{strawberry}>s>"
```